# Is there a way to select integers that are distinct with a margin in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with three columns: `id`, `name`, and `value`. I want to select all the rows that have a distinct value and no other row has a value within a range of for instance `3`. So if the values in the rows are:

```
14, 15, 15, 17, 20, 23, 23, 23, 24, 29, 33, 32, 32, 33, 38, 38, 43
```

Then I want to get back the rows with the values `20`, `29`, and `43`.

Comment: @forpas because it appears twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table having the following structure

| id | value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | ... |
| 2 | 15 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

You can do as follows

```
select id, value, ...
from thetable t1
where not exists (
  select t2.value 
  from thetable t2 
  where abs(t2.value - t1.value) < 3 
        and t1.id <> t2.id)
```

Ie select all rows from the `table`, where there is no other row (ie with a different `id`) in which the difference of `value` is less then `3`.

You need `abs(...)` because otherwise comparing for instance `43` from `t1` to `20` from `t2` will give you `-9` which is of course `< 3` and thus it will wrongly remove `43` from the result. And checking the different `id` is also important, because otherwise, it will at some point compare `20` from `t1` to `20` from `t2` which gives a difference of `0` and thus, it will be wrongly removed form the result also.

See also [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGgofH7u68U3TGENTxFws5/0)

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite 3.28.0+ you can use `COUNT()` window function with the `RANGE` frame type adjusted to your condition:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           ORDER BY value
           RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING
         ) AS cnt
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT id, name, value FROM cte WHERE cnt = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BGnL-Fp7).